# Div loaded through Ajax no longer works with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am using CakePHP for an application where I am trying to add some Ajax functionality to update in page content.

JavaScript libraries: Prototype, Scriptaculous, jQuery, jEditable

By default: Load 5 rows and option to load 10 more rows on the page

Editable options: clicking on a field will use the jEditable to allow users to edit the fields and save.

Current situation: When the page loads for the first time, all functionalities work, but when I load 10 more rows, the JavaScript functions stop working.

Here is the index view file which calls an element containing all the entries with the JavaScript functions:

```
<div id="latestResults" class="wrap">
     <?php 
        echo $this->element('current_entries', array('entries' => $entries));
    ?>        
     </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var clientsInput= <?php echo json_encode($clients); ?>;
 $j('.client').editable("<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'entries', 'action'=>'editEntryClient')); ?>/", { 
     data   : clientsInput,
     name   : 'data[Entry][client_id]',
     type   : 'select',
     onblur : 'submit'
 });

 //Inline editor for projects

 var projectsInput= <?php echo json_encode($projects); ?>;
 $j('.project').editable("<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'entries', 'action'=>'editEntryProject')); ?>/", { 
     data   : projectsInput,
     name   : 'data[Entry][project_id]',
     type   : 'select',
     onblur : 'submit'
 });

 //Inline editor for tasks

 var tasksInput= <?php echo json_encode($tasks); ?>;
 $j('.task').editable("<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'entries', 'action'=>'editEntryTask')); ?>/", { 
     data   : tasksInput,
     name   : 'data[Entry][task_id]',
     type   : 'select',
     onblur : 'submit'
 });

 //Inline editor for hours spent

 $j('.hours_spent').editable("<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'entries', 'action'=>'editEntryHoursSpent')); ?>/", { 
     name   : 'data[Entry][hours_spent]',
     onblur : 'submit'
 });

//Inline editor for notes

 $j('.notesCol').editable("<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'entries', 'action'=>'editEntryDescription')); ?>/", { 
     name   : 'data[Entry][description]',
     onblur : 'submit'
 });

 //Load more

 $j('#load_more').click(function(){

    //Get last id
    var currentNumberOfRows = $j('.row').length;
    var newNumberOfRowsToDisplay =currentNumberOfRows + 10;
    var urlToGet = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=> 'entries', 'action'=>'displayCurrentEntries')); ?>/" + newNumberOfRowsToDisplay; 
    $j.get(urlToGet, function(data){
            $j('#latestResults').html(data);

        }); 

});
```

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('inpage', array('inline'=>true)); ?>
```

current_entries.ctp

```
<?php
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($entries as $entry):
                    $class = null;
                    if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
                        $class = ' class="altrow"';
                    }
                    $div_id = null;
                    $div_id = "id='entry_".$entry['Entry']['id']."'";
                    $row_id = "id='row_".$entry['Entry']['id']."'";
                ?>
            <!-- ROW 1 -->
                <div class="row">

                        <!-- clients -->
                        <div class="clientCol">
                            <div class='client result' id='client_<?php echo $entry['Entry']['id']; ?>'><?php echo $entry['Client']['name']; ?></div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- projects -->
                        <div class="projectCol">
                             <div class='project result' id='project_<?php echo $entry['Entry']['id']; ?>'><?php echo $entry['Project']['name']; ?> </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- tasks -->
                        <div class="taskCol">
                             <div class='task result' id='task_<?php echo $entry['Entry']['id']; ?>'><?php echo $entry['Task']['name']; ?> </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- hours -->
                        <div class="hoursCol">
                             <div class='hours_spent result' id='hours_spent_<?php echo $entry['Entry']['id']; ?>'><?php echo $entry['Entry']['hours_spent']; ?> </div>
                        </div>


                        <!-- Date -->
                        <div class="dateCol">
                             <?php echo $entry['Entry']['date_of_task']; ?>
                        </div>

                        <!-- notes -->
                        <div class="notesCol" id='description_<?php echo $entry['Entry']['id']; ?>'>
                                 <?php echo $entry['Entry']['description']; ?>
                        </div>

                        <!-- submit -->
                        <div class="submitCol">
                            <div class="options">
                                <a class="duplicate" href=""></a>
                                <?php echo $ajax->link('', array('controller'=>'entries', 'action' => 'delete', $entry['Entry']['id']), array('class'=>'remove', 'update'=>'latestResults'), 'Are you sure you want to delete this?'); ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="clear"> </div>

                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <!-- //ROW 1 -->            

            <!-- Load Row -->
                <div class="row load">

                        <a href="#" id="load_more">Load 10 more rows</a>
                </div>
            <!-- // Load Row -->
```

When the page loads, all the $j('div.class').editable('') functions work. But whenever it is loading more rows, all these functions stop working alltogether. I might be missing something really simple here, but any help or guidance on this would be brilliant. Note that the loadmore only updates the #latestResults in page through the Ajax call.

Thanks a million in advance.

Regards
Tas

Comment: Check console. Is it showing some error?

Comment: Is this something to do with binding editable with 'live' rather than 'click'?

Comment: Nope - the console is not showing any errors.

Comment: Are you calling the $j('div.class').editable('') functions again after the 10 rows are loaded?

Comment: These functions are present on the page after the latestResults div. Imagining that this is going to work even after the div is updated through the Ajax call.

Comment: Is there any reason why the JavaScript functions will not work for an element that has been loaded through Ajax? Note that the JS functions/codes are not inside document.ready() function.

Comment: I have done some research and it seems like I will need to use 'on' or 'live' so that when the dom elements are loading through the Ajax call, the functions still work. Based on this, I have changed the function with the following:  $j('.client').on("click", function(){
   $j(this).editable("<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'entries', 'action'=>'editEntryClient')); ?>/", { ... still not working.

Comment: You should try `$(document).on("click",".client",function(){your code goes here});` Basically you need to attach that event to the document or something that already exists...

Comment: Thanks - that has solved the issue!!! Now I understand why it did not work with "on". As the whole div was updating, the dom with .client was reloading and it seems like 'on' was getting detached from it.